# How model constraints work seperatly on different views and model fields in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo

I have two views. One form view and 2nd one is a wizard.
i am having problem that model constraints applying on both view where i needed to apply on form view. Form view having a button which opens a new view (wizard) with some drop down options to save.

why Missing Record error occurring ?

Views showing following warning messages ..

1 ..."One of the records you are trying to modify has already been deleted (Document type: Visits management). "    Appear on popup window

2.... You can not create new visit until patient checked out !

here is my code below

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('status', 'student_id')
def _checkstatus(self):

    students_to_check = self.mapped('student_id')
    exist = self.search([('student_id','in',students_to_check.ids),('id','not in',self.ids),('status', '=', 'open')])
    if exist:
        raise ValidationError(_('You can not create new visit until student checked out !' ))
```

....................

Let me explain scenario,I have top 2 menus and models 1 . Students 2. Registrations ...
When i need to register a student via 'Registration' menu its done normally. Registration form view containing a pop up wizard to register with status 'New'.Problem occur, when this procedure starts from Students form view (containing a button to open Registration form view) and Registration form view open a new pop up (window) wizard which changes student status from 'New'  to 'Register or something else'.Here i am facing warning message 'Missing Records ...One of the records you are trying to modify has already been deleted (Document type: Registration management).'

Comment: these might be helpful to you. https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-create-constraints-in-openerp.html

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242383/why-missing-records-warning-message-appearing-in-odoo-10)